# How to prevent the application from restart after completing the phone calls in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android field. In my application tab activity is used. If any incoming call is arrived, the application is restarted after answering the call. Is there any way to prevent the restart application?.
I also included the
  in manifest file.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here please tell me how you added views in side the tab.

If you are using tab ,it is little bit difficult to handle the app .

Suppose if you are adding view in side an **ArrayList** make it **public static** .

In side the classes which are extends **TabActivity** write the code for OnResume,OnPause 
methods like Activity.

Try it .

Comment: i am using the grid view to display image. image detail are stored in ArrayList.